# Insert DIV Just after <body> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('<div id="tools" style="text-align:right;float:right;"><input type="button" value="Print this page" onclick="window.print();return false;" /><input type="button" value="Save this page" onclick="go_saveas();return false;" /></div>').insertBefore('body');
    });
</script>
```

Basically, I need to insert that whole Div just right after the `<body>` tag:

```
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tools"..
...
```

Which works in Firefox but doesn't work in IE 7, what do I have to change to fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're using [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore). That will try to put it between `head` and `body`; not what you want. Try [`prependTo`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo).

Comment: @Bryan: Whoops, my mistake. That's what I intended.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/XDFMt/:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('<div id="tools" style="text-align:right;float:right;"><input type="button" value="Print this page" onclick="window.print();return false;" /><input type="button" value="Save this page" onclick="go_saveas();return false;" /></div>')
            .prependTo('body');

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using insertBefore, using prependTo.
This way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('<div id="tools" style="text-align:right;float:right;"><input type="button" value="Print this page" onclick="window.print();return false;" /><input type="button" value="Save this page" onclick="go_saveas();return false;" /></div>').prependTo('body');
    });
</script>
```

The insertBefore inserts your code before the tag . That's why it gives you problems.
You were lucky that Firefox corrected it to what you wanted.
Now, prependTo inserts it inside your tag, but before all its content. ;)